# Azure DevOps parallelism error even tho I added subscription in billing and increase no of parallel jobs

Tags: azure-devops, parallel-processing

I am getting parallelism error in Azure DevOps. I have add subscription to billing and then increase Microsoft-hosted and Self-hosted number of parallel jobs but still getting create when I run pipeline

[image]

`error`

```
 ##[error]No hosted parallelism has been purchased or granted. To request a free parallelism grant, please fill out the following form https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request
```

Comment: Is your project private or public?

Answer (score 0):

this is resolve by adding the service plan